# bash get list length when list name is not fixed

Tags: bash

Suppose I have two lists:

```
lista="a b c d"
listb="e f"
```

I would like to write a function that returns the number of items on a given list:

```
>>foo $lista
4
>>foo $listb
2
```

I've tried using `${#<varname>[@]}` syntax, also `${#!<varname>[@]}`, unsuccessfully.

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

You can use `wc -w` for this:

```
$ lista="a b c d"
$ wc -w <<< "$lista"
4
$ listb="e f"
$ wc -w <<< "$listb"
2
```

From `man wc`:

> **-w, --words**
>
> print the word counts

---

To make it function, use:

```
list_length () {
        echo $(wc -w <<< "$@")
}
```

And then you can call it like:

```
list_length "a b c"
```

Answer (score 13):

Put them into BASH array and look at array length.

```
a=($lista)
echo ${#a[@]}
4

a=($listb)
echo ${#a[@]}
2
```

Answer (score 5):

If you indeed want to write a function, you can take advantage of normal parameter parsing and the fact that `$#` contains the number of parameters passed:

```
 foo() { echo $#; }
```

Comment: what about for `#export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,3,4,5,6,7`

Comment: @CharlieParker, if you have different requirements, please ask a new question.